# Magit has trouble commiting - there is a problem with the editor

Tags: magit

When I try to commit using magit I get the following error;

```
 1 git … commit --
Waiting for Emacs...
*ERROR*: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
error: There was a problem with the editor '/opt/emacs/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=/tmp/emacs1000/server'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Here are the versions of software I'm using

```
Magit 20160814.1615, Git 2.9.0, Emacs 25.0.50.2, gnu/linux (Debian wheezy 7)
```

I run emacs as a server.

If I type the following into a file within my git project and eval the buffer I get the following;

```
(with-editor
  (let ((magit-git-debug t)
        (process-environment
         (cons "GIT_EDITOR=printf '[%s]\n' \"$EDITOR\"" process-environment)))
    (magit-git-insert "commit")))[/opt/emacs/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=/tmp/emacs1000/server]
[/home/map7/code/testproject/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG]
```

On the command line if I do the following

```
$ export GIT_TRACE=1 
$ export GIT_EDITOR='printf "[%s]\n" "$EDITOR"'                                             
$ git commit 
10:48:43.558746 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'commit'
10:48:43.561811 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: '.git/hooks/pre-commit'
10:48:43.563366 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'status' '--porcelain'
10:48:43.563595 exec_cmd.c:120          trace: exec: 'git' 'status' '--porcelain'
10:48:43.564766 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain'
10:48:43.574334 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'printf "[%s]\n" "$EDITOR"' '/home/map7/code/testproject/.git/COMM
IT_EDITMSG'                                                                                                           
10:48:43.574637 run-command.c:195       trace: exec: '/bin/sh' '-c' 'printf "[%s]\n" "$EDITOR" "$@"' 'printf "[%s]\n" "
$EDITOR"' '/home/map7/code/testproject/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG'                                                                  
[emacs -nw -q]
[/home/map7/code/testproject/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG]
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
10:48:43.581313 git.c:350               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get' 'oh-my-zsh.hide-dirty'
```

**UPDATE**

I just restarted emacs and now I can commit again, but I don't know for how long.

I can re-enact a similar problem if I do the following

1. Stage my changes in magit using 's' on a file
2. Go to commit hitting 'c c'
3. Cancel the commit 'C-c C-k'

Now I get the same error as I was getting before, when trying to commit.

**UPDATE: error in Backtrace**

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  isearch-done(t)
  isearch-cancel()
  server-goto-toplevel(#<process server <24>>)
  server-process-filter(#<process server <24>> "-dir /home/map7/code/angularjs_nested_routes/ -current-frame -tty /dev/pts/31 dumb -file /home/map7/code/angularjs_nested_routes/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG \n")
```

**UPDATE**

I've been busy testing my configuration by remarking parts out as suggested. I recently had the same error, but manage to fix the error by killing off some of my buffers. I didn't take note of which buffers, but I will next time. This may suggest that it's a certain state instead of configuration?

Comment: `25.0.50` is an old unstable version of Emacs, have you tried with `25.1-rc1` (or wait a day or so for rc2)? Also, the command line test should be `export GIT_EDITOR='printf "[%s]\n" "$EDITOR"'`, note the quotes have to go around the printf *and* its arguments.

Comment: Try evaluating `(setq debug-on-signal t)` before committing to get a backtrace with the error.

Comment: I ran that setq in the *scratch* and when the error happens I don't get anymore information.

Comment: you did use `debug-on-SIGNAL`, not `debug-on-ERROR`? (the latter doesn't work with emacsclient). With `debug-on-signal` you should get a backtrace buffer popping up in Emacs (that's what I got when I inserted an error by hand).

Comment: debug-on-signal didn't work so I just tried debug-on-error and this worked. I'm running exwm (Emacs X Windows Manager), so I don't think I'm running a emacsclient, although exwm does start an emacs daemon.

Comment: `magit` tells `git` to run `emacsclient` to edit the commit message. If you run `(progn (load "server.el") (load "isearch.el"))` do you get any more detail in the backtrace?

Comment: Re `debug-on-signal` vs `debug-on-error`, see this [emacs-devel thead](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2016-08/msg00149.html). Since it's working opposite for you, it seems like you have a hacked Emacs? I suggest again to use 25.1-rc1.

Comment: Based on your backtrace, the issue seems to only occur when isearch is enabled. Try to reproduce the issue after making sure isearch isn't active.

Comment: npostavs: I've updated and now I'm on 25.1.50.2 and I've just had the same problem happen again

Comment: tarsius: how do I disable isearch?

Comment: Isearch is the interactive search you start with `C-s`. You can exit it by pressing `RET`. But since this issue persists, it's unlikely that you accidentally started a search. But these isearch functions should not be called non-the-less. You should try to reproduce this issue without your personal (and possibly starter-kit) configuration.

Comment: Since I've upgraded to magit 20160824.917 I haven't been having the problem, so I'll wait and see if the magit team has fixed this issue.

Comment: @map7 if the issue does not come back, then please delete this.

Comment: @tarsius The issue has raised it's head again on the new magit version 20160902

Comment: @tarsius Should I report this as a magit issue to better keep track of this problem?

Comment: I am not sure opening an issue would help. I still think the issue is with your personal configuration, a package you have installed, and/or a starter-kit you are using. I cannot reproduce this issue and you will have to come up with steps that allow me to do so. Please try to reproduce starting with an Emacs in which nothing but Magit has been loaded. Install Magit as described at https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Installing-from-the-Git-repository.html, and then run `make emacs-Q`.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce the issue like that, then you have to narrow the issue down to a specific parts of your init file by commenting out parts and then trying to reproduce the issue, then other parts, and so on until you have found the bad part. I would suggest looking for things that involve isearch to speed up the process a bit. Please also see http://www.lunaryorn.com/2015/11/29/reproduce-bugs-in-emacs-Q.html.

Comment: I just ran into this, temporarily. The problem disappeared after restarting Emacs - Emacs 25.1.1, Magit - 20160907.945, Git 2.9.3 on Debian.

Comment: I'm currently running: 20160902.1451, Git 2.9.0, Emacs 25.1.50.2 on Debian and I still get the problem every so often. I'm trying to nail it down to reproduce it's very hard.

Comment: @Tyler Can I see you configuration, maybe we are using a similar package which is breaking magit.

Comment: I ran into this again today. However, it's not a magit problem: I can reproduce it from the command line: `emacsclient tmp.txt` gives me the error: `*ERROR*: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`. The same problem is reported here: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2016-06/msg00003.html - again, intermittent and not consistently reproducible. However, it is clear now that the problem is external to magit. @tarsius

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this too, and traced the problem a fraction further, within the `isearch-done` function.  The source of the `stringp` error is this line:

```
(with-current-buffer isearch--current-buffer
```

`with-current-buffer` expects that its first parameter is a string, but at this point `isearch--current-buffer` is `nil`.  I'm 80% sure that this is because `server-goto-toplevel` calls `isearch-cancel` just in case `isearch` is currently active, presumably because if it was it would interfere with the server or client somehow - but if it's not active then this error happens.

The good news is that it seems that [this bug has already been fixed](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21091), and indeed manually patching `isearch.el` with this fix seems to do the trick!

Comment: Hmm, `server-goto-toplevel` only calls `isearch-cancel` if `isearch-mode` is non-nil, I wonder how `isearch--current-buffer` and `isearch-mode` get desynchronized. Unlucky `C-g`? Or do you recursively edit while isearching (the code around that looks tricky, perhaps it doesn't recover from it correctly)?

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure but I think I probably do *occasionally* recursively edit while isearching, although maybe sometimes by accident ...

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Adam Spiers' answer, I ran the following

```
(dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (when (bound-and-true-p isearch-mode)
      (message "Try isearch-ing in %s" buffer))))
```

which identified a buffer.  I then went to that buffer, started `isearch`, exited `isearch` normally, and then things went back to normal.  The issue for me was that `isearch-mode` was non-`nil` (so it thought it had to call isearch-cancel), but `isearch--current-buffer` was `nil` (so cancelling threw an error).

Comment: The code snippet here provides a solution that allows fixing the issue quickly and without having to restart Emacs or upgrade, or do anything time-consuming. I ran the snippet, got the name of the buffer that was problematic, started and cancelled `isearch` there, and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

While it can of course not be completely ruled out that Magit and/or `with-editor` in some way at least contribute to this error, it most likely is causes by a local configuration issue.

This question can therefore not be answered by someone who does not have access to the machine on which the error occurs. We can only provide tips about how to best locate the cause.

The cause of the error has to be isolated by performing a binary-"commenting-out"-search on the user's init file and/or by making educated guesses about what might be the cause and looking specifically in those places. Since the issue apparently cannot be reproduced consistently, the latter might be the only option.

Since `isearch-cancel` appeared in a backtrace, looking for strange things involving `isearch` would be a good start.

Also check the values of the hooks `server-visit-hook`, `server-switch-hook`, and `server-done-hook`. Is there anything on those hooks that shouldn't be?

Comment: We have checked hooks with C-h v and there is nothing there which is obvious. I've got one machine in error state and another working. We have been able to fix the problem now by closing buffers instead of a restart of emacs.